# How to improve my PHP library (procedural scripting vs OOP)

Tags: php

Over the last 18 months i have been hard at work teaching myself PHP & Jquery and so far have become quite good at it but not having a "mentor" i have developed my own "model" for building webapps / sites. it goes like this...

I have my front end page (HTML) and a js script which i fill with lots of jquery ajax (using a get or post method then pass on a command to the php) commands which in turn reference a sometimes large php file made up almost entirley of one big "switch / case" command with all my various options.

my question is this, is there a better way to do this?

i want to advance in my skills, where should i take my model next?

Comment: Just to be a bit of a stinker: your title isn't really a question, nor is it a good indicator of what you're actually asking. Consider revising?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case I would make the switch to Object Oriented Programming. I've been in a similar situation like you but wasn't satisfied anymore at how my websites looked with simple procedural scripting. Switching to OOP will take quite some time to get used to, but in my opinion it was all well worth the effort.

Take your time learning OOP. First, check http://www.php.net/ to learn about objects and classes and afterwards read a book on the subject (Php Objects, Patterns And Practice by Matt Zandstra is a very good one [http://www.amazon.com/PHP-5-Objects-Patterns-Practice/dp/1590593804](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590593804)). You will find out why a lot of people have made a switch to the OOP approach for web apps.

When you are used to the way of thinking in OOP, choose a framework. It doesn't make sense to write code for things that have been written 100 times before and are tried and tested approaches to common problems. A framework covers all the basic annoying stuff you shouldn't be spending your precious time on. But only choose a framework when you have really grasped the way of thinking with OOP. It's always best to learn the basics first instead of jumping right in the middle by directly choosing a framework.

Comment: Thanks so much this was the kind of advise i was after, i like the look of this book and will buy it, time to make the transition then i think, THEN move onto a framework, many thanks buddy :-)

Comment: No problem :) Good luck with your journey into OOP

Answer (score 1):

To put it simply: start learning the pros and cons of the various programming patterns. Sounds like you're doing [Front Controller](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/frontController.html), which is fine for simple, one-off projects. The GoF book, [Design Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633612), is supposed to be really good. A friend of mine really likes the [Head First](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596007124) version...

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I do the similar.

I have one file, index.php or so, and urls looks like this

```
index.php?what=faq
index.php?what=news
....
```

and I use `switch{}` `case: break;` commands

and it looks like this

```
switch($_GET['what']){
     case "faq": 
          include("Templates/faq.php"); 
     break;
     case "news":
          include("Templates/news_v2.php");
     break;
}
```

so just a tip: do not proccess any code in cases, just include your template file and do everything there

Comment: hummmm interesting, i see, i like it! :-)

Comment: I made it just a little diffrent. If you create webapps having large ammounts of your what-parameters and if you have to handle userrights, building a huge switch-construct results in kind of "bad code". I build a function checking the what-parameter compared to userrights (database) and include the files automatically. If the userrights doesnt match or the what-parameter is wrong error-pages will come up automatically. You could watch codes of other webapps like free forums to give you some ideas how to solve this problem.

Comment: yes, but I think it's little bit insecure to do something like include('Templates/'.$_GET['what'].'.php'); :)

Comment: And there is Array: `Array('faq' => 'faq.php', ...);` and `array_key_exists` or `isset` in that case.

Comment: @hakre: Yes, that's briliant idea, in case I won't add ANYTHING else in case excluding include. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

"is there a better way to do this?"
What is this? Structure code? Achieve asynchronous updates on individual widgets on a page? Not have giant and potentially unmaintainable blobs of gunk?

Consider exploring [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/) to move more in the direction of web application development.

Comment: Yes this is all structured code, i havent made the transition to OOP as yet as i have hammered structure into my head and find it hard to break away from, i have briefly been exploring frameworks but find them a little confusing, do you think it best i move in this direction? it just seems i have to re-learn everything again!!

Comment: Codeigniter is not giving a good OO example, it's basically tying together functions from classes that are instantiated as singletons. Singletons are just global variables.